# Wait for Keyboard to Hide

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

so, basically I need to know if there is a way to have a observer o another method that is called when the keyboard is hidden.

The problem i have is that after dismissing the Keyboard, I commit 2 Animations, one to take the view to the original position (since I move up the view so the user can see the textfield while typing) and an Animation Flipping the View but the Flip occurs before the Keyboard is fully hidden so I have a little graphic glitch.

I've tried sleep(), and another wait methods without luck.

The Code Basically is this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textFieldi{

[textFieldi resignFirstResponder];
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

     [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:0];

     CuantoFaltaiOSAppDelegate * del = [CuantoFaltaiOSAppDelegate instance];

     del.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, del.headerView.frame.size.width, del.headerView.frame.size.height);

     [UIView commitAnimations];

     return YES;
}
```

The problem is that the Keyboard isn't fully Hide and the Flip is perfomed, so i need a way to wait for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register for the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:(id)
                                         selector:(SEL)
                                             name:(NSString *)
                                           object:(id)];
```

**Example:**

Subscribe to the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` as follows (put this in your `viewWillAppear:` method):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

This assumes you have a method called `keyboardDidHide:` (this is where your animation logic will reside)

Comment: +1 Good answer, I just added a specific example and closed my answer to help.

Comment: Thanks, Mostly solved my issue but another came up, but is easily fixable with a BOOL :D